# Qtcreator cannot create new project

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have installed Qtcreator (version 6.0.2) on my windows 10 machine (Qt version: 5.15.2, visual studio 2019 x86). The problem is that the list of presets (template projects)  is empty and the create button is grayed out, so I cannot create any new project.
Some facts: I have used QT online installer to install the all package (QT, Qtcreator,...). In the setting (tools-> options-> kits) I see that the QT and the compiler are detected. I can compile and run the example projects.
Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Does it show any yellow or red sign beside the Kit ?

Comment: @prosach: no, there is no sign.

Comment: Are you able to create a new project using the menu _File > New File or Project..._?

Comment: @m7913d no, creating new project either using welcome window or the menu opens the same dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because of plugins. I've disabled then enabled some plugins (try a group then another). The issue was gone. You can try this way (Help > About Plugins).

Comment: In my case the problem was caused by the plugin: Qt Quick-> StudioWelcome

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with new install. Go to Help > About plugins.
Then uncheck :

- GenericProjectManager

[image]

Comment: Probably this problem can occur because of different plugins. In my case was because of the plugin Qt Quick -> StudioWelcome.